# c# calculation sum

Tags: c#

```
var deviation = frequencies.Sum(value => (value.Key * value.Value))
```

can anyone tell me how the sum work?

Comment: Yes.  The documentation can tell you.

Comment: In future, please either Just Google It, or if you can't make sense of the Google results, please paste *more code* so we can be sure of what we're looking at. One line is not enough!

Comment: BTW, you should accept more answer...

Answer (score 1):

[`Sum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345537.aspx) is an extension method on [`IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx), part of LINQ.

It goes through all elements in the collection and uses the passed in [Lambda Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) for getting a value per item. It them sums them up and returns the result.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `frequencies` is a `Dictionary` containing the number of times a particular number has been seen (i.e `key` is the number, `value` is the occurrence count for that number), this will go over all key-value pairs in the dictionary and for each calculate the product of key*value and sum them all up. The sum method itself is an extension method that you pass a lambda expression that states how each item should added.

Answer (score 0):

It uses the `Sum()` LINQ method. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534734.aspx):

> Computes the sum of the sequence of
>   Double values that are obtained by
>   invoking a transform function on each
>   element of the input sequence.

It is effectively equivalent to `frequencies.Select(value => (value.Key * value.Value)).Sum()`, which goes over every item in the list/dictionary, and multiplies the dictionary key by the value it represents. It then adds every one of these computed values together.

Answer (score 0):

It uses a lambda expression - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx

The lambda expression says "Given value, I will take the Key of the value and the Value of the value, and multiply them together". The Sum function presumably applies that function to each element of frequencies and sums the results of each calculation together (I'm guessing here but there's not enough information to tell).

Answer (score 0):

Check out this blogpost by Jon Skeet where he reimplements Sum:

[Reimplementing LINQ to Objects: Part 28 - Sum](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/01/08/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-28-sum.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I guess frequencies is an IEnumerable so the Sum method actually is [this Sum method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534734.aspx) What it does is call a method for each element in the IEnumerable and the method is:

```
return value.Key * value.Value;
```

so the deviation is the sum of all these values. (which is NOT the deviation)

Answer (score 0):

Sum just iterates through the collection in your case a keyvalue pair

```
var deviation = frequencies.Sum(value => (value.Key * value.Value))
```

is short hand for

```
var sum = 0.0M; // or 0.0D; // or what ever type?
foreach(var pair in frequencies) {
    sum += (pair.Key * pair.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the my simplest implementation of Sum method

```
public static class LinqExt 
    {
        public static decimal? MySum<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> list, Func<TSource,decimal?> selector)
        {
            decimal? result = 0;
            foreach (var p in list) 
            {
                result += selector(p);
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
```

it does not check for any exceptions and totally trusts the incoming parameter values to be true. Furthermore i would ask the community how decimal result should have been initialized. 
you can use MySum method exactly like Sum e.g

```
List<int> values = new List<int>{1,2,3,4};
var sum = values.MySum(x=>x);
```

this will give you sum of all integers in the list